# Magento 2 Observer after account confirm by email

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email, registration, confirmation

I need to trigger a Email after the account is verified from email link by the customer, Need the observer.

Comment: what is your version? what have you tried? honestly just look through the code if an event get fired

Answer (score 0):

You can use **controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_confirm** observer.

OR

Using plugin of **activate** method:

**Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement**

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function activate($email, $confirmationKey)
{
    $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($email);
    return $this->activateCustomer($customer, $confirmationKey);
}
```

Comment: Thank You, But Cant find this observer in in vendor and in https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html

Comment: You can find controller_action_predispatch_. Magento add with full action name.